# Receiver window not getting data through PostMessage in windows

Tags: sendmessage, postmessage, window-messages

void SendDataFromWorkerThread(HWND handle)

{

```
 int *x = new int(10);

 ::PostMessage(handle, user_defined_message_id, 0, (LPARAM)x);
```

}

While receiving on different thread..

void GetDataFromWorkerThread(WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)

{

```
int *x = (int*) lparam;

// But it does not give the right data.
// It gives 0 at that memory address.
//( Also memory Address pointed by lparam is different from what was sent)
```

}

My application is single thread where I am delegating some work( return some data, above x value "10" ) to the worker thread.
I am getting the message properly but not the data.